# TextView fill with points

Tags: android, layout, textview

Sorry by my english

I have one RelativeLayout and 2 textviews like that

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView10"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

And I want to separate the two elements by points. Like that:

TextView9 ...................................... TextView10

Other Text more long ................................... 69

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without java code:

drawable/dotted.xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="line">

    <stroke
       android:color="#C7B299"
       android:dashWidth="10px"
       android:dashGap="10px" />
</shape>
```

view.xml:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/dotted" />
```

And also set:

```
view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```